# А правда ли..?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Попалась недавно такая информация, что популярный сейчас бандинтский жаргон "лох" - это аббревиатура от выражения "лицо, обманутое хулиганами". Правда ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, прежде чем задавать вопрос, поищите его через поиск. Такой вопрос уже был. Это слово неясной этиологии. Я помню время, когда этот слово появилось в речи обычных и даже интеллигентных людей (я не знала, что это бандитский жаргон), и я восприняла его как производное от "лопух"  - с похожим звучанием и значением. Лопух, лопухнуться - лох, лохануться. Возможно, это из разряда народной этимологии...

Comment: Да, Ваша версия  - это чистой воды народная этимология...

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован иначе и его нельзя считать повтором.  
Администратор.

Answer (score 0):

Я читал в одном этимологическом словаре (автора уже не помню, возможно, Грачёв с его словарём арготизмов), что лох и олух - однокоренные слова. Это, конечно, не этимология, но шаг в направлении к.